# How to set Auto flash mode and camera in custom build IOS camera

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making custom camera to take pictures. How to set the AutoFlash Mode using AVCapture Device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by setting `FlashMode` property in `AVCaptureDevice`

```
[avCaptureDevice setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto];
```

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

Also, In order to set hardware properties on an AVCaptureDevice, such as focusMode and exposureMode, clients must first acquire a lock on the device. Then after setting mentioned properties, clients must release locks.

So, final code is as:

```
if ([avCaptureDevice hasFlash]){

    [avCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];

    [avCaptureDevice setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto];

    [avCaptureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```